# How to pause Jssor in another class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, fancybox, jssor

I have a slide show program called Jssor which also uses jQuery.  I have links inside the slide show which invoke Fancybox3 to display a text box describing that slide.  I need the slide show to pause while the focus is on Fancybox.  Jssor has a method called $Pause and $Play and I can get it to work (outside of the jQuery class) by using buttons (manually clicking.)  The main issue is that I need it to work without user interaction.  My plan is to put the code into Fancybox.js so it will pause/play the slide show automatically.  I know almost nothing about JavaScript so please keep it simple.

I left out (below) a bunch of code thinking I would make this simple and hoping it’s not needed for this question.  This code does work, I just need to know how to make/invoke the last line (using JS not HTML) without user input.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // A bunch of code
    //...........................
    var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);
    function Play() {               
        jssor_1_slider.$Play();
    };
    function Pause() { 
        jssor_1_slider.$Pause();
    };

    $("#playButton").click(Play);
    $("#pauseButton").click(Pause); 
};
</script>
// HTML 
<input id="playButton" type="button" value="Play" />
<input id="pauseButton" type="button" value="Pause" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are designed for purposes like this. Example:

```
$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({
  onInit : function() {
    jssor_1_slider.$Pause();
  },
  afterClose : function() {
    jssor_1_slider.$Play();
  }
});
```

Obviously, this code should go after you have created `jssor_1_slider` variable.